# How can I properly integrate a git push with nuget?

Tags: github, nuget

I have a Github repository that I'd like to use as a source for my nuget package. Currently, I push both repositories separately:

**1.** `git push origin master`

**2.** `nuget pack` and `nuget push MyPackage.0.0.0.1.nupkg`

**BUT** I'd like to be able to simply call `git push origin master`

Ideally, I'd use some kind of bridging/service hook that would up the nuget version and do the pushing automatically using the git source.

Does anyone know of a good bridging mechanism for this kind of thing?

Answer (score 9):

You could use [MyGet](http://www.myget.org)'s Build Services (that I helped co-found) for that and link your GitHub repository to your feed. This allows you to have each check-in being built and a package being pushed on your CI feed. From there, you could use the push upstream feature to push it to NuGet.org (or any other feed).

Check this blog post for more information: http://blog.myget.org/post/2012/12/17/Add-packages-from-GitHub-BitBucket-and-CodePlex-using-MyGet-build-services.aspx

Comment: What if the repo is a solution with multiple projects? How do I determine which project sould be packaged in the nuget (or even included in the build)?

Comment: You could hook into our build services using any of the ways documented here: http://docs.myget.org/docs/reference/build-services-build.bat-examples

Comment: I managed to do it with the build-configuration for Release and a nuspec-file. Excellent service! :) Just what I needed